# I cannot figure out how to change this into a table that has only one row and no null values. Is there a way to make this a loop?

Tags: sql

[screenshot of code and table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjWS2.png)

```
DELETE FROM summary;
INSERT INTO summary(g_rating_total)
SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM detailed
WHERE rating = 'G';
INSERT INTO summary(pg_rating_total)
SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM detailed
WHERE rating = 'PG';
INSERT INTO summary(pg13_rating_total)
SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM detailed
WHERE rating = 'PG-13';
INSERT INTO summary(r_rating_total)
SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM detailed
WHERE rating = 'R';
INSERT INTO summary(nc17_rating_total)
SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM detailed
WHERE rating = 'NC-17';
INSERT INTO summary(total_movies)
SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM detailed;

SELECT * FROM summary;
```

I am trying to get the total count of each different rating and insert them into another premade table name summary. I had to initially create a summary table and detail table put data into details from multiple other tables than transform that data into something that populates the summary table. The issue I am having is inserting the count result into the summary table without creating 6 rows where each iteration of COUNT() adds a new row with null values for all previous and new rows for each column.

Comment: I don't see how you could automise it when the relationship between the ratings and the column names is not consistent R -> r_ is fine but PG-13 -> pg13_ when NC17_ -> nc17_ ? You could write a procedure but it would be complicated.

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of code and data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a case statement for each column e.g.

```
INSERT INTO summary(g_rating_total, pg_rating_total, …)
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 'G' Then 1 else 0 end)
, SUM(CASE WHEN rating = 'PG' Then 1 else 0 end),
,…
FROM detailed;
```

Comment: I used the the method provided by @NickW and it worked. I actually tried to use that previously and it was giving me issues and I didn't save the code to see the difference in it but I'm glad this worked! Thanks alot!